# How to mark certain property as required in json content

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I am writing an application where I do need to handle some scenarios beforehand in my controller class like certain property must have been provided otherwise status code would be BadRequest. Here is my class lookalike.

```
public class MyClass
{
   [Required]
   public IEnumerable<NewObject> NewObjects { get; set; }
}

public class NewObject : INewObject
    {
        public NewObject(string typeName, IEnumerable<Property> properties)
        {
            TypeName = typeName;
            Properties = properties;
        }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public string TypeName { get; }
        public IEnumerable<IProperty> Properties { get; }
    }

public interface IProperty
    {
        string Name { get; }
        object Value { get; }
    }
```

Now though I have marked `TypeName` as required property and if I do not pass that in json content while sending request from swagger, json deserialization doesn't fail. I tried to search but I got an answer that setting `Required` to `Always` should work.
Below is the Json Content I am passing through swagger:

```
{
  "NewObjects": [
    {
      "Properties": [
        {
          "Name": "string",
          "Value": ''
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I wrote below piece of code too by looking at one of the solution:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Still it's not working:
Note: I am using Newtonsoft.Json version 11.0.1

This seems to be swagger issue because when I serialize input C# object and when again deserialize it, I am getting proper error.
For example in my controller class if I say:

```
var input2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input))
```

Then input2 throws an exception.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? That isn't even valid json (`''`) and it doesn't map to your class.

Comment: The above example is Json content which I am providing through swagger and ' ' is a valid value. No issue there.

Comment: As you wish. The [json spec](https://www.json.org/) though says _"A value can be a string **in double quotes**, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array"_

Comment: Here is the thing
My Properties class got two fields namely "Name" and "Value". In JSON content I am not providing TypeName here so deserialization should be failing as per my expectation.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` works for me - _"JsonSerializationException: Required property 'Name' not found in JSON"_ - but without a reproducible example we can't help you find out why it isn't working for you.

Comment: So you needed to do some extra settings to get that exception?

Comment: I also added below piece of code still it's not working:

var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [FluentValidation](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-fluent-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-part-1-the-basics/). If I am not mistaken it is designed to validate data in jsons forms specifically.

```
using FluentValidation;

public CertainActionValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.PropertyName).NotEmpty()
}
```

You can add plenty of additional conditions in there.

Comment: Thanks for reply but do I really need some external NuGet package for just sake of validation? I believe there should be some way I can achieve this using Json attributes.

Comment: @Jaydeep , we are using `FluentValidation` in our project and trust me its worth it.Validations are so clean and readable, also testing is done easy as well, I'd strongly recommend it :)